# "Inappropriate ioctl for device" from termios with pipes

Tags: python, pipe, stdin, ioctl, termios

I was working on a project yesterday and I came across an issue that I haven't encountered before. I'm current using argparse to ask for an input filename, and I'm adding support for piping a file via stdin to my program. I've got it all set up and working, except for this termios issue I'm encountering whenever I pipe a file to my program, and I was wondering if anyone knows a solution. The exact error I'm getting is

```py
    old_settings = self.termios.tcgetattr(fd)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

This specifically is coming from the [getkey](https://github.com/kcsaff/getkey) module, because I need something for non-blocking input (feel free to inform me of better options). I'm assuming it's happening because its standard I/O streams aren't connected to a terminal because of the pipe, but I don't know if there's a way I can actually fix that and I can't really find any solutions on stackoverflow or Google. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
# Assuming filename is test.py, running
# python3 test.py
# works, but running
# cat test.py | python3 test.py
# or
# python3 test.py < test.py
# results in an error
import sys
import termios

termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin.fileno())
```

Comment: *"I've got it all set up and working, except for this termios issue ..."* -- So then why do you think you need to fetch these attributes?

Comment: @sawdust I mentioned the getkey module in my post, that's what's causing the issue. I'm open to suggestions of different modules to use, and also editing the code of the getkey module is a valid solution, I just don't know what code I would need to add since I cant find any solutions to this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a solution using the `pty` module which I didn't know about before. The example I gave can be fixed by using `pty.fork()` to connect the child to a new pseudo-terminal. This program seemed to work:

```py
import pty
import sys, termios

pid = pty.fork()
if not pid:
    # is child
    termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin.fileno())
```

I also found a solution for if the error is coming from a new python process created with `subprocess`. This version utilizes `pty.openpty()` to create a new pseudo-terminal pair.

```py
import subprocess, pty, sys

# Create new tty to handle ioctl errors in termios
master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()

proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'my_program.py'], stdin=slave_fd)
```

Hope this helps someone else out.

Comment: I was facing this issue running under pytest - the subprocess being launched was using termios and expecting to be able to get input from stdin. By changing to the pseudo-terminal using pty, as you show above, this resolved the issue! Thanks!